# jmap supports ascii format for heap dump and binary dump format

Tags: java, heap-dump

I use jmap to dump heap memeory

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=test.hprof 22035
```

as far as I know, heap dump ascii format exists. but execute below command

```
jmap -dump:format=a,file=test.hprof 22035
```

jmap Usage printed.

ASCII format doesn't exist?

And I like to know heap dump binary format documentation. 
googling.. there is no answer, no documenation.

Here is the snippest of binary format file.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no text format, only:

> ```
> -dump:<dump-options> to dump java heap in hprof binary format
>                      format=b     binary format
> ```

This makes sense, dumping memory of JVM in text format would take lots of GiB... This file can be read by heap dump analyzers like [Eclipse mat](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) or [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).

## See also

- [Recommendations for a heap analysis tool for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064427)

Answer (score 1):

just pipe the binary output through a filter like `less` (has various options for display of control characters), or `xxd`, which does a hexdump and ASCII dump by default.

there can be no true ASCII format since this is binary data; ASCII doesn't include any byte with bit 7 set, which would leave out a lot of important information.

some documentation is here: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/perfanal/java.hprof.txt